# block element with position:absolute does not use full width. why?

Tags: html, css

I have the following test page.

The section element is a block element. As far as I know block elements take the full width that is available. But this seems not to be in this case. Why?

I can easily fix this by setting a width or left+right property. But I would like to understand why this block element behaviors different. If I switch position to static. It takes the full width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>position</title>
    <style>
        .element {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <article>
            <section class="element">
                <h2>element (absolute)</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
                    invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
                    duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
            </section>
        </article>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Position `absolute` combats with display `block`. With `absolute` you should use `inset` or `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom`. Of course, if the parent of the absolute element has a position set (ie not static), then you can use `width: 100%` to fill the parent's width fully. Most times you would want to set the position of the parent as `relative` in order to achieve this effect with `width: 100%`; Of course, when using `width: 100%` you must keep margins and paddings in mind,

Answer (score 1):

In [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) you can find the rules that define the width of a `position:absolute` element.

In your case you only defined left so you fall into this rule:

> 'width' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'left' is not 'auto', then the **width is shrink-to-fit** . Then solve for 'right'

then

> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).

The *shrink-to-fit* algorithm is the same one used for inline-block element, table element, float element, etc

Note that `display:block` play no role here because a `position:absolute` will by default have block as computed value for display. More detail here: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo